# Formulate multivariate multistep time series forcasting using traditional machine learning, NOT deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

How do you represent multivariate multistep data using traditional machine learning? I know this seems like a tailored problem for RNN/LSTM, but I am wondering what the alternative machine learning solution would be.

Ex.

```
time, feature_1, feature_2, feature_3
1     25         150        0.7       
2     25.3       147        1.1        
3     25.5       145        0.8
...
10    26.7       165        1.2
```

Now I want to predict feature_1 at time 10 using the first 3 time steps of all features, and get a dataset like this

```
feature_1,       feature_2,       feature_3,       target
[25,25.3,25.5]   [150,147,145]    [0.7,1.1,0.8]    26.7
```

Comment: Would you mean something like vector autoregression?

Answer (score 0):

You can always reduce the forecasting problem to a tabular regression problem and then apply any tabular regression algorithm you like. [Here](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/41231210/Machine_Learning_Strategies_for_Time_Ser20160114-28513-1pqgoe9.pdf20160115-19908-phg1xc.pdf?1452888125=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3DMachine_Learning_Strategies_for_Time_Ser.pdf&Expires=1591785169&Signature=Mx6tIKC-mcM5kgaPHpL80cLYfIu2gVYUVDFdB3Weza8AiWVqM65fnWcjMYDTHF0AjVAXcaAbuLY6dQMTFrC7MytZNBP11rnleGIhUfwmJj9Tn5DrVUWiMRumsf4udnYl65JEXcP9bo02sXl184OYYpe-E7iNShICon3Nry~8279l361lGgAvRb1Cd6NA9fsDV0bsLNTXx9KON~cfiww3-YDdmuaEYnNocLbTr7yVim~iEUs2W2xFZlGVUJfK7dX67ilQIKLFDA9csUBjCanZfugOBuy8HW685ZLitJhMM75XQ3jFbZwMBKls1JkG0mm8pz~VqB4NoR86p~EO1Fkf6Q__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA)'s a good explanation of how this works.